# Determining if this set is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I have the following here:

> For the following sets $A$ and binary relations $\sim$, decide of $\sim$ defines an equivalence relation on $A$ or not.
>
> a)
> Set: $A=\mathbb{R}$
> Relation: $x \sim y$ if $x=ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Q}$
>
> b)
> Set: $A=\mathbb{R}$
> Relation: $x \sim y$ if $x=ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Q}\backslash \{0\}$

I know I have to use the reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties here.

I know that:

Reflexive means that for all $a\in A$, $a \sim a$

Symmetry means that for all $a,b\in A$, if $a \sim b$, then $b \sim a$

Transivity means that for all $a,b,c\in A$, if $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$ then $a \sim c$.

I understand the definitions and if the question just gave a bunch of elements in sets, I could do this without issues. How do I use the properties here though? Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Apply the three conditions; do we have an $a \in \mathbb Q$ such that $x=ax$?

Comment: Do we have a $b \in \mathbb Q$ such that if $x=ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb Q$, then $y=bx$?

Comment: And similar for transitivity.

Comment: Related: http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Did you mean to say $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ for $x=ay$ and $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ for $y=bx$?

In the case of the first ones, yes, I can pick $a=1$ so it's reflexive.

For the second one could I not pick $a=1$ and $b=1$?

For the last one, similarly, could I not pick $a=b=c=1$ to satisfy the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that:
>
> Reflexive means that for all $a\in A$, $a \sim a$ 
> Symmetry means that for all $a,b\in A$, if $a \sim b$, then $b \sim a$ 
> Transivity means that for all $a,b,c\in A$, if $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$ then $a \sim c$.

Correct, but to avoid confusion with the definitions, let us use $x,y,z$ and also less words and more logic symbols.

Reflexive: $\forall x\in A: x \sim x$ 
Symmetry: $\forall x,y\in A: (x \sim y\to y \sim x)$ 
Transivity: $\forall x,y,z\in A: (x \sim y\land y \sim z\to x \sim z)$.

Next, replace $A$ and $\sim$ with the given definitions

> a)
> Set: $A=\mathbb{R}$
> Relation: $x \sim y$ if $x=ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Q}$

Reflexive: $\forall x\in\Bbb R:(\exists a\in\Bbb Q~. x = ax)$ ? 
Symmetry: $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R:((\exists a\in\Bbb Q~.x = ay)\to (\exists b\in\Bbb Q~.y = bx))$ ? 
Transivity: $\forall x,y,z\in\Bbb R:((\exists a\in\Bbb Q~.x = ay)\land(\exists b\in\Bbb Q~. y = bz)\to(\exists c\in\Bbb Q~. x =cz))$ ?

Finally, do these claims hold up to scrutiny?

> Well for every real number ($x$) there does exists a rational number ($a$) where $x=ax$; because $1$ is a rational number. Therefore this relation is reflexive over the real numbers.
>
>  Symmetry and Transitivity are investigated similarly.

> b)
> Set: $A=\mathbb{R}$
> Relation: $x \sim y$ if $x=ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Q}\smallsetminus\{0\}$

Clearly you just need to consider how the answers above would change when none of the rational numbers may be zero.  Think carefully.

Comment: For part a, could I not just use $a=1,b=1,c=1$ which will satisfy every property? For $a=1$, we get $x=x$, for $a,b=1$, we get $x=y$ and $y=x$ and if $a,b,c$ are all $1$, we get $x=y=z$ which is what I need.

Comment: No, that will not suffice, @FutureMathperson .  For symmetry you have to establish that *every* pair of $x$ and $y$, which satisfies $\exists a\in\Bbb Q~.x=ay$, will also satisfy $\exists b\in\Bbb Q~.y=bx$.  That is *not* just the pairs of $x$ and $1x$.

Comment: Basically: If you have *some* rational $a$ satisfying $x=ay$, does that imply that the $b$ which satisfies $y=bx$ is also rational?

Comment: Yes it must be right? Suppose $x=1$ and $y=2$, this means $a=\frac{1}{2}$. This means for $y=bx$, we have $2=b(1)$ meaning that $b=2$. In general, this is always true since all integers are rational numbers.

What about my reasoning for the transitive property?

EDIT: I suppose, $0$ could potentially cause issues since the symmetry property is not satisfied if $a=0$ since this implies $b=\frac{1}{0}$ which is undefined.

This means that a ISN'T transitive and b IS transitive I guess?

Comment: Indeed: if $x=0$ *and* $y\neq 0$ then $0=0y$ but $\lnot\exists b\in\Bbb Q~. y= 0b$; ie $(0\sim y)\land\lnot(y\sim 0)$.  Therefore $\exists a\in\Bbb Q~.x=ay$ is not symmetric, but $\exists a\in\Bbb Q{\smallsetminus}\{0\}~.x=ab$ is symmetric (because $\lnot\exists a\in\Bbb Q{\smallsetminus}\{0\}~.0=ay$ unless $y=0$)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!